# What is the part number for the i-mid source wheel on a 9th generation Civic?

Tags: steering-wheel

I have a 9th Generation Honda Civic (2012). It has wheel buttons which have worn down (actually transparent the cheap paint came off), and one of the sides even chipped. This is on the left side of the steering wheel.

Where can I buy this button? I can't find it in the [online catalog](http://estore.honda.com/honda/parts/view-honda-parts-catalog.asp?m=2012-civic-4-ex-5at&year=2012&dl=207805)

[image: imid button]

Comment: Can you add additional info, like the model of civic and trim package you have?  As well, the engine.  There's no way to find the part unless you give all the model info.  Cheers.

Comment: Honda 2012 EX, 1.8

Comment: I think it's #1   at this url    http://www.hondapartsnow.com/parts-list/2012-honda-civic-2dr_ex-ka-5at/steering-wheel-srs.html?PNC=1

Comment: Wow, hahah I just found it 13 seconds after you by going through a thousand listings [on eBay until I got to this one which gave it away.](http://www.ebay.com/itm/35880-TR0-A01-Steering-Wheel-Volume-Cruise-Switch-button-For-2012-Civic-Sedan-/281793628827?fits=Year%3A2012%7CMake%3AHonda%7CSubmodel%3AEX&hash=item419c358a9b:g:-8UAAOSwqv9V7ap9&vxp=mtr). Honda really needs to get their parts catalog straight.

Comment: Award yourself the answer. :-) did I find the right part too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. The part number for the 2012 is `35880-TR0-A01`. The part isn't listed on the official Honda Parts site but you can find it on HondaPartsNow. It's called `Switch Assy., Audio Remote`.

http://www.hondapartsnow.com/genuine/honda~switch~assy~audio~remote~35880-TR0-A01.html